# Searching for multiple strings in a stream at once without doing "text1" or "text2" or "text3" or

Tags: python, string, bots

I was wondering if there's a way in python that I can search for multiple strings in a stream at once without jamming them all into one line. Can I put them in some sort of list and substitute that for the long line of 'or's?

```
if re.search("japan" or "japanese" or "nihon" or "nippon", str(comment.body).lower(), re.IGNORECASE):
      return True
```

This is what I have right now, I just to make it look neater instead of searching for every variation of japan I can think of. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just so you know, what you have right now doesn't look for anything other than "japan". As a simpler example, `re.search("a" or "z", "xyzzy")` returns None even though z appears twice in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with list comprehension, if you prefer how this looks

```
search_terms = ["japan", "japanese", "nihon", "nippon"]
if any([x in str(comment.body).lower() for x in search_terms]):
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just put your search terms in a list and use Python's `in` operator.

```
search_terms = []
search_terms.append('japan')
search_terms.append('japanese')
search_terms.append('nihon')
# etc
# OR
search_terms = ['japan', 'japanese', 'nihon', 'nippon']

for term in search_terms:
    if term in comment.body.lower():
        return True
```

Incidentally, you can do this with a one liner using `any()`

`if any(term in comment.body.lower() for term in search_terms)`

Comment: If there were a lot of strings, especially if many of the strings have common prefixes, it might also be beneficial to use `re.compile` te to build a quick regular expression search automaton based on the exhaustive list of terms:  r`japan|japanese|japon|japans|nihon|nippon`. This might be faster or slower depending on the dataset. Word boundary markers `\b`, and ignore-case flags might also avoid the need for word splitting and whitespace trimming.